# Бот вырубается error 403 bot was blocked by user?

Tags: python, telegram

```
import telebot

    import sqlite3
    import random
    from conf import *
    from text import *
    from button import *
    from get_photo import *
    
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token = token)
    
    connect = sqlite3.connect('users.db', check_same_thread = False)
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
    def welcome(message):
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEGHLtjTDhHV8ia0JMgDJytwVL5iHS43wACTwADrWW8FGuRHI2HrK-TKgQ')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open(no_fol, 'rb'), hi, reply_markup = follow)
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands = ['winner'])
    def random_ch(message):
        if message.chat.id == admin:
            num = str(random.randint(0, 5))
            bd = list(cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM login_id ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;").fetchone())
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, wins + bd[0])
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, fail_win, parse_mode = 'html')
    
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def fas(call):
        if call.data == "check":
            member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id = id_1, user_id = call.from_user.id)
            if member.status in statuses:
    
                member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id = id_2, user_id = call.from_user.id)
                if member.status in statuses:
                    d = ('https://i.imgur.com/LQqD5mK.jpg')
                    bot.edit_message_media(
                        media = types.InputMediaPhoto(d, caption = good, parse_mode = 'html'),
                        #media = media,
                        chat_id = call.message.chat.id,  
                        message_id = call.message.message_id, 
                        reply_markup = vse
                    )
    
                    #Добавление в базу данных
                    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_id(
                      id INTEGER,
                      username TEXT
                    )""")
                    connect.commit()
    
                    people_id = call.message.chat.id
                    people_us = call.from_user.username
                    cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM login_id WHERE id = {people_id}")
                    data = cursor.fetchone()
                    if data is None :
                        user_id = call.message.chat.id
                        username =  call.from_user.username
                        cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO login_id  VALUES ("{user_id}" , "{username}") """)
                        connect.commit()
                    else:
                        pass
    
                else:
                    #sticker = bot.send_sticker(call.message.chat.id, oda_s)
                    bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, open(no_fol, 'rb'), caption = er_f, parse_mode = 'html', reply_markup = follow)
            else:
                #sticker = bot.send_sticker(call.message.chat.id, oda_s)
                bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, open(no_fol, 'rb'), caption = er_f, parse_mode = 'html', reply_markup = follow)
        else:
            pass
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Сама ошибка
[image: ошибка]

Comment: У меня такое оч часто при запуске бота, однако при повторном запуске все ок

Comment: Мне нужно что бы бот не вырубался